# Grails domain class beforeDelete is not working as transactional

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an user domain class with attributes like username, fullName, ... etc. and a UserRole association class.

In my domain class I have the following code on the beforeDelete method

```
def beforeDelete() {
    UserRole.removeAll(this);
}
```

In the UserRole class I have the removeAll method like this:

```
static void removeAll(User user) {
    executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE user=:user', [user: user]
}
```

The call to the delete method is done in my UserService class

```
def delete(User userInstance){
   userInstance.delete()
}
```

What I am expecting is: When deletion fails a rollback should be performed, but even when deletion fails all the UserRole associations are being deleted.

Am I missing something? 
The beforeDelete method is not wrapped in the same transaction as the userService.delete(User userInstance) method?

Or should I move the UserRole.removeAll() call to the UserService class?

Grails Version: 2.3.11

Hibernate: 3.6.10.16

Comment: Trying moving the call to the service (removeAll) and call it, see if it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing in Grails is transactional without configuration except services. A service with no `@Transactional` annotations and no `static transactional` property is transactional. Adding one or `@Transactional` annotations lets you customize the behavior for the service, and/or per-method. The only way to make a service non-transactional is to remove all annotations and set `static transactional = false`. Nothing else in a Grails app is transactional.

You can use `@Transactional` in controllers and the domain class `withTransaction` method, but both are hackish and services should always be used.

You can use dependency injection in domain classes, so I'd move all of the update code to a service method and call that from the domain class event method:

```
class MyDomain {

   ...

   def myService

   def beforeDelete() {
      myService.beforeDeleteMyDomain this
   }
}
```

Or, since you're deleting in a service already, you can just combine everything in one method:

```
def delete(User userInstance){
   UserRole.removeAll userInstance
   userInstance.delete()
}
```